# Django Filefield path depends on folder. Weird bug?

Tags: python, django, django-models

When I run shell from project's root category I get the following result:

```
>>> from generations.models import *
>>> Generation.objects.all().first().file.path
'/Users/marijus/workspace/preeti/media/data/58/input/IRIS.csv'
```

Which is good and what I want.

However when I run shell or any other script with django context from other directory I get the following result:

```
─$ cd scripts 
╰─$ python ../manage.py shell
>>> from generations.models import *
>>> Generation.objects.all().first().file.path
'/Users/marijus/workspace/preeti/scripts/media/data/58/input/IRIS.csv'
```

notice scripts appended before /media which results in an error when I try to access the file from scripts directory.

my models:

```
def get_upload_path(instance, filename):
    return "media/data/%s/input/%s" % (instance.id, filename)

class Generation(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_path, blank=True, null=True)
```

Is this some kind of bug or is FileField's path supposed to depend on folder from which I'm trying to access it.

Comment: Can you your media settings in settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django's `FileStorage` [uses `os.abspath`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/files/storage.py#L202) to get files location. On the other hand `os.abspath` [calls `os.getcwd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) to get the path. This is what causes path to be relative to current directory, which is useful in local environment.

If you want to set it to some absolute location you need to set [`MEDIA_ROOT` setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#media-root).